# How to parse multi-language documents without UTF-8 specific code

Tags: c++, c, parsing, csv, unicode

I'm writing a small program that takes characters written in a CSV spreadsheet, in many different common languages, and injects them into smaller files specific to each language.

I know that an 8-bit string is too small for this, and assumed the 16-bit `wchar_t` datatype would be enough.  (I'm not interested in emoji or dead languages, just Japanese, Mandarin, Spanish, and a few others.)  However, researching the topic, it seems `wchar_t` or `wstring` is not sufficient for this task? "UTF-8" and "locales" come up often, but those subjects feel far, far too complicated/general for what I want to do... and I'd like to avoid them for now if I can!

Given a CSV document containing these common languages, on Windows, is it possible to read these characters into memory, parse them, and then write them to a new file, using only the standard C I/O / parsing library and minimal knowledge of Unicode? For instance, `wstring`,`fgetws()`, `wcstok()`, and `wcsstr()` are all functions I'm currently comfortable with.  (I'll learn Unicode someday, to be sure, but it's far too big a subject for me to take on right now.)

My data is parsed in such a way that I only look for delimiters such as quotes, punctuation, and a few English words.  The files I'm reading from are either produced by the program itself, or exported from a spreadsheet program... I'm not sure how to specify the encoding with the C library though, is it perhaps automatic?  The spreadsheet program allows me to pick the encoding, though it doesn't offer UTF-16 as an option, which is unfortunate since that seems to map the easiest to my implementation of `wstring` (16 bit).

Comment: Just a small note about `wchar_t` and its size, it's not guaranteed to be 16 bits, it can be other sizes too (most likely 32 bits). The actual size is depending on the compiler.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I know, on mine it's 16-bit so I thought I should specify it's size with the type, in case it was imporant

Comment: If there's anything I can do to improve the question and avoid your downvote, let me know!  I'm sorry if my tone is impolite, I was only hoping to avoid a general answer about unicode, and learn only what I need to do this right now with the tools I'm comfortable with

Comment: I think this is quite a reasonable question. Probably some people are thinking it might be too broad, and there might be difficulty with "simplest" as opinion-based. Maybe it would help you get a better response if you omitted "simplest" and just framed the question in terms of using only the standard library. "Simplest" could be implied by the quality of the answers.

Comment: What exactly does your parsing involve? Many operations can just be done with normal 8bit strings and a minimal understanding of utf-8 encoding. Especially, if you are only searching for delimiters or certain substrings and just copy the strings around otherwise, there is no reason to go for anything else.

Comment: How are the files formatted?  If it's utf-8 (you can always hope), then 8-bit strings is plenty.  (Each character in the text takes multiple chars, that can be true even in UTF-16 - for example Ä can either be 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS' (U+00C4) or 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A'  plus 'COMBINING DIAERESIS' (U+0308).

Comment: And as mksteve mentions: How is your input data formatted?

Comment: @MikeMB - I added that info into the question (and reworded it to be less subjective, thank you)

Comment: What Martin Bonner and MikeMB are emphasizing is that you have know which character set and encoding your files are in so you can read them. So, which? Are they all the same?

Comment: @TomBlodget - Yeah, they're all in utf-8 I think.  I'm not sure what encoding the csv files are though, that get produced by the program, but I assume the spreadsheet will be able to pick which encoding it wants to use when it opens the file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have to manipulate / search for characters outside of the ASCII character set, I'd higly recommend working with UTF-8 and normal `char` and `std::string` functions. That will save you a lot of headaches and increase portability.

The thing about UTF-8 is that it encodes the "common" symbols exactly the way as ASCII would. It also ensures that no part of a multibyte character has the same value as an ASCII character so there is no danger of a mixup and you can just use the "normal" functions to search for your delimiter characters and even mix those strings with normal ASCII strings. That way, you also don't need to worry about 16 vs 32 bit `wchars` or different endianess. Finally, UTF-8 is the universal exchange format across the internet.

As for how to create UTF-8 strings: Inside your program, you can just prefix your string literals with [`u8`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). And if your editor doesn't support the symbol in question, you can use a [Unicode escape sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).
Otherwise use your text program's / consoles encoding options. The standard read and write functions are, again, agnostic to UTF-8 encoding.

To demonstrate what I mean, here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const char* u8cString = u8"汉语\u002dHello;World汉语";
std::string u8cppString(u8cString);

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    u8cppString.insert(0,input);
    u8cppString.append("ASCII-text");

    size_t delPos = u8cppString.find(';');
    std::string first =  u8cppString.substr(0, delPos);
    std::string second = u8cppString.substr(delPos+1);
    std::cout << first << "\n";
    std::cout << second << std::endl;
}
```

Of course this code is overly complex for what it achieves, but I wanted to demonstrate that even with some random Chinese characters all functions work as expected.
Now whether or not the Chinese characters get displayed correctly on your console depends on the system settings (Windows is somewhat problematic) but you should see all ASCII characters where you expect them and the line break is at the position of the `;` delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows `wchar_t` is a UTF-16 representation of Unicode data.  That means that if the data you are processing contains the dead characters (beyond the basic plane), then the encoding would create multiple `wchar_t` values to express one Unicode code point.

The important point in this work, is how are the CSV files already encoded.

1. UTF-16 - in which case, read and write the lines from source to destination using `wstring` and `fgetws` etc
2. UTF-8 - use `fgets` to read the coded data, then use `MultibyteToWideString` to convert from UTF-8 to `wchar_t`.
3. language-specific code page.  In this case you need to read the data using `fgets` again, but specifically identify the code-page the file was written in, and convert to wide char.

Comment: If it's utf-8, I'd use char + std::string.  If all you want is strtok, then that will be fine in a utf-8 string.

Comment: Switching to a 16 bits representation such as utf-16 is asking for trouble.  It is more headaches than handling utf-8 and keeping the data in a byte oriented format.